# SQL Server Query Idle Time Out

Tags: sql-server

I have a shared hosting plan for my website which is developed in ASP.NET and SQL Server. 
I have set the CommandTimeout = 180  for all the sql commands. Now the hosting provider says that our queries are running long/remains active up to 30 mins. They are advising us to set some IDLE SESSION TIME OUT in SQL scripts. I am not  aware of any such thing. I have searched the web that also not proved helpful. So please tell me what exactly is **"IDLE SESSION TIME OUT in SQL scripts"** and how to set it. Thanks

Comment: What kind of queries these are that takes upto 30 minutes?

Comment: These are simple select queries. I think the hosting company point is that the queries remain there in ideal state after finishing execution.

Comment: Do you close the connection after your query finishes executing? Show some sample code please. Note that the word is "Idle" and not "Ideal".

Comment: Yes we close the connection after executing the query objDA.CloseConnection();
objDA.DisposeConnection();

Comment: Please add the example code by editing your question with the example of query (omit the query text if necessary).